# Retrieve form values after redirecting

Tags: php

Some one should please guide me on how i can retrieve forms data after i redirect a user back to the page of the form due to error occurrence.

In some website registration page i observe that when i submit the form and it happens that my data contains error, i will be redirect back to the registration page displaying the error message but the data that i fill early will still appear on the input boxes, only the input box that contain error will be empty, please i don't know how to do this on site i only know how to redirect and display error message.

Answer (score 1):

All POST data will be lost after a redirect. If you really want to save those form values, you will need to store them as session variables. Example:

```
$_SESSION['form']['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['form']['email'] = $_POST['email'];
```

Check out [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) for some basic session-usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) or [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) to save the values.

or you can use javascript to validate your form inputs. So the page won't reload. so datas will be retained.

Answer (score 0):

you can submit values to same page (same page which include form)

and check if informations is submitted using:

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])){
   //validate
}else{
   //display form
}
```